# Why does my async function always return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

It seems im using async wrong, can anybody spot what I am doing wrong?

This is the function I am waiting on:

```
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export async function firebaseAcceptTradeOffer(tradeOfferID, userData) {
  var tradeInstanceID;
  var senderID;
  var receiverID;
  var senderItemsTemp;
  var receiverItemsTemp;
  var response;
  var tradeOffer = db.collection("tradeOffers").doc(tradeOfferID);
  return tradeOffer
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      senderItemsTemp = doc.data().sendersItems;
      receiverItemsTemp = doc.data().receiversItems;
      senderID = doc.data().senderID;
      receiverID = doc.data().receiverID;
    })
    .then(() => {
      var itemInTrade = false;
      senderItemsTemp.forEach((item) => {
        db.collection("listings")
          .doc(item.itemID)
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().status !== "listed") {
              itemInTrade = true;
            }
          })
          .then(() => {
            receiverItemsTemp.forEach((item) => {
              db.collection("listings")
                .doc(item.itemID)
                .get()
                .then((doc) => {
                  if (doc.data().status !== "listed") {
                    itemInTrade = true;
                  }
                })
                .then(() => {
                  if (itemInTrade) {
                    tradeOffer.update({
                      status: "declined",
                    });
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    db.collection("trades")
                      .add({
                        tradeOfferID: tradeOfferID,
                        senderTradeStatus: {
                          created: true,
                          sentToSeekio: "current",
                          inspection: false,
                          sentToPartner: false,
                        },
                        receiverTradeStatus: {
                          created: true,
                          sentToSeekio: "current",
                          inspection: false,
                          sentToPartner: false,
                        },
                        postagePhotos: [],
                        inspectionPhotos: [],
                        senderPaid: false,
                        receiverPaid: false,
                        senderUploadedProof: false,
                        receiverUploadedProof: false,
                        senderID: senderID,
                        receiverID: receiverID,
                        messages: [
                          {
                            message: `Trade created. A representative, will message this chat shortly with instructions and postage address. If you would like more information about the trading process, head to seekio.io/help. Thank you for using Seekio!`,
                            sender: "System",
                            timestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(
                              new Date()
                            ),
                          },
                        ],
                      })
                      .then((docRef) => {
                        tradeInstanceID = docRef.id;
                        tradeOffer
                          .set(
                            {
                              status: "accepted",
                              tradeInstanceID: docRef.id,
                            },
                            { merge: true }
                          )
                          .then(() => {
                            var receiver = db.collection("users").doc(senderID);
                            var notification = {
                              from: auth.currentUser.uid,
                              fromUsername: userData.username,
                              type: "tradeOfferAccepted",
                              time: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(
                                new Date()
                              ),
                              seen: false,
                            };
                            receiver
                              .update({
                                notifications: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                                  notification
                                ),
                              })
                              .then(() => {
                                response = {
                                  sendersItems: senderItemsTemp,
                                  receiversItems: receiverItemsTemp,
                                };
                                return response;
                              });
                          });
                      })
                      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
                  }
                });
            });
          });
      });
    });
}
```

And here is where I am calling it:

```
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  async function acceptTradeOffer() {
    var tradeOfferID = currentTradeFocus;
    var senderID = "";
    setLoading("loading");
    if (userData !== null && tradeOfferID !== "") {
      const response = await firebaseAcceptTradeOffer(
        currentTradeFocus,
        userData
      );
      console.log(
        "RESPONSE FROM FIREBASE SERVICE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: ",
        response
      );
      if (!response) {
        setErrorMsg("One of the selected items is no longer available.");
      } else if (
        response.sendersItems !== null &&
        response.receiversItems !== null
      ) {
        setSenderItems(response.sendersItems);
        setReceiverItems(response.receiversItems);
        toggleConfirmScreen("cancel");
        setLoading("idle");
        setItemsSet(true);
      }
      fetch(
        "https://europe-west2-seekio-86408.cloudfunctions.net/sendMail?type=tradeUpdate&userID=" +
          senderID
      ).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading("idle");
      });
    }
  }
```

So basically I want to go and check if any of the items in this 'trade' are not equal to 'listed' (which means they are not available, I want to return `false`, if not, then I return the array of items so the trade can continue.

**EDIT**: I've tried to rejig it all and it's half working. A top level look at what I am trying to do:

```
User wants to accept a trade offer for some items >
Check through all items to make sure they are available and not sold >
If so, accept the trade >
Then once its accepted, go and cancel all remaining trade offers that include items from this accepted trade, cause they are not available anymore.


//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export async function firebaseAcceptTradeOffer(tradeOfferID, userData) {
  console.log(
    "----- starting firebaseAcceptTradeOffer--------- ",
    unavailableItem
  );
  //==============
  var tradeInstanceID;
  var senderID;
  var receiverID;
  var senderItemsTemp;
  var receiverItemsTemp;
  var unavailableItem = false;
  var response;
  var itemsArray;
  var notListed = false;
  //==============
  var tradeOffer = db.collection("tradeOffers").doc(tradeOfferID);

  unavailableItem = tradeOffer
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      senderID = doc.data().senderID;
      receiverID = doc.data().receiverID;
      itemsArray = doc.data().sendersItems.concat(doc.data().receiversItems);
    })
    .then(() => {
      itemsArray.forEach((item) => {
        db.collection("listings")
          .doc(item.itemID)
          .get()
          .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().status !== "listed") {
              notListed = true;
            }
          });
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      return notListed;
    });

  console.log(
    "-----unavailableItem at the end of method --------- ",
    unavailableItem
  );

  //^^^^^^^^^^ here i am getting a promise result of false (which is correct) but HOW CAN I ACCESS IT

  if (unavailableItem) {
    tradeOffer.update({
      status: "declined",
    });
    return false;
  } else {
    response = await createTrade(
      tradeOffer,
      tradeOfferID,
      senderID,
      receiverID,
      userData.username
    );
    console.log("response from createTrade", response);
    return response;
  }
}
```

I am getting a promise object back with the value `false` above. False is correct value I am expecting, but how can I access it? its in the form of a promise object?

Comment: You're mixing `async` + `await` with `.then()` callbacks. Don't do that.

Comment: In short, you get `undefined` because you don't return any value in the second `then()` handler. You need to refactor your code to use `Promise.all()` and appropriately hook it in your chain of promises. Refactoring code of this size is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. If you are still stuck after taking a crack at it using `Promise.all()`, then edit your question with your next attempt.

Comment: As you are obtaining many documents by their IDs, you can benefit from making use of [this helper function](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527) which should help with refactoring your code.

Comment: @samthecodingman thanks m,an, going to look into trying to use Promise.all and will add an edit if I fail, thank you!

Comment: @samthecodingman well i got stuck haha, just made an edit above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some time on my hands, so let's break this down.

#### Notes on Variables

If you aren't using TypeScript (and even if you are), I highly recommend inserting the type into the name of your variables.

```yaml
db                # ✔ by convention, either firebase.database() or firebase.firestore()
tradeOffer        # ❓ type unclear, could be a number, an object, a string, etc
tradeOfferDocRef  # ✔ a DocumentReference
trades            # ❓ type unclear, plural implies a collection of some sort
tradesColRef      # ✔ a CollectionReference
```

You may also encounter these:

```yaml
doc               # ❓ by convention, a DocumentSnapshot, but with unknown data
tradeDoc          # ✔ implies a DocumentSnapshot<TradeData> (DocumentSnapshot containing trade data)
```

When using just `doc`, you need to look around where its used for context on what this `DocumentSnapshot` contains.

```
db.collection('trades').doc(tradeOfferID).get()
  .then((doc) => { // contents implied to be TradeData
    const data = doc.data();
  });
// or
tradeDocRef.get()
  .then((doc) => { // contents implied to be TradeData
    const data = doc.data();
  });
```

You should rename `doc` as appropriate, especially when using `async`/`await` syntax, so you don't end up in situations like:

```
const doc = await db.collection('trades').doc(tradeOfferID).get();
/* ... many lines ... */
const senderID = doc.get("senderID"); // what was doc again?
```

As you've tagged `reactjs` in your question, this implies you are using modern JavaScript.

Ditch any use of `var` and replace it with the block-scoped versions: `const` (prevents reassigning the variable)  or `let` (similar to `var`, [but not quite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#description)). These are safer and prevents the chances of accidentally overwriting something you shouldn't.

You can also make use of Object destructuring to assign your variables.

```
const senderID = doc.data().senderID;
const receiverID = doc.data().receiverID;
const itemsArray = doc.data().sendersItems.concat(doc.data().receiversItems);
```

can become:

```
const { senderID, receiverID, sendersItems, receiversItems } = doc.data();
const itemsArray = sendersItems.concat(receiversItems);
```

If you ever need only a single property out of a document, you should use [`DocumentSnapshot#get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get) instead of [`DocumentSnapshot#data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) so it will parse only the field you want instead of the whole document's data.

```
function getUserAddress(uid) {
  return firebase.firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(uid)
    .get()
    .then(userDoc => userDoc.get("address")); // skips username, email, phone, etc
}
```

#### Notes on Promises

```
var senderID;
var receiverID;
var itemsArray;

tradeOfferDocRef
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    senderID = doc.data().senderID;
    receiverID = doc.data().receiverID;
    itemsArray = doc.data().sendersItems.concat(doc.data().receiversItems);
  })
  .then(() => {
    /* use results from above */
  });
```

While the above code block functions as intended, when you have many of these variables like this as you do, it becomes unclear when and where they are set.

It also leads to problems like this where you think the variable has a value:

```
var senderID;
var receiverID;
var itemsArray;

tradeOfferDocRef
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    // this line runs after the line below
    senderID = doc.data().senderID;
    receiverID = doc.data().receiverID;
    itemsArray = doc.data().sendersItems.concat(doc.data().receiversItems);
  });

// this line before the line above
console.log(senderID); // will always log "undefined"
```

This can be avoided in one of three ways:

- Returning data to pass through to the next handler (you wouldn't use this for this example, only if the next `then()` handler is elsewhere):

```
tradeOfferDocRef
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    const { senderID, receiverID, sendersItems, receiversItems } = doc.data();
    const itemsArray = sendersItems.concat(receiversItems);
    return { senderID, receiverID, itemsArray }; // pass to next step
  })
  .then((neededData) =>
    /* use neededData.senderID, neededData.receiverID, etc */
  });
```

- Using the data within the same handler:

```
tradeOfferDocRef
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    const { senderID, receiverID, sendersItems, receiversItems } = doc.data();
    const itemsArray = sendersItems.concat(receiversItems);

    /* use results from above */
  });
```

- Using `async`-`await` syntax:

```
const tradeDoc = await tradeOfferDocRef.get();

const { senderID, receiverID, sendersItems, receiversItems } = tradeDoc.data();
const itemsArray = sendersItems.concat(receiversItems);

/* use results from above */
```

#### Writing to Firestore

Your current code consists of the following steps:

```
1. Get the trade offer document</li>
2. If successful, pull out the sender and receiver's IDs, along with any items in the trade
3. If successful, do the following for each item in the sender items array:
  a) Check if any of the sender's items are unavailable</li>
  b) If successful, do the following for each item in the receiver items array:
    - If **any item** was unavailable prior to this, decline the trade & return `false`.
    - If all items **so far** are available, do the following:
      a) Create a document containing information about the trade with the needed data
      b) If successful, edit the trade offer document to accept it
      c) If successful, create a notification for the receiver
      d) If successful, return the traded items
      e) If any of a) to d) fail, log the error and return `undefined` instead
4. Return `undefined`
```

In the above steps, you can see some problems with your promise chaining. But aside from that, you can also see that you create and edit documents one-by-one instead of all-at-once ("atomically"). If any of these writes were to fail, your database ends up in an unknown state. As an example, you could have created and accepted a trade, but failed to create the notification.

To atomically write to your database, you need to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) where you bundle a bunch of changes together and then send them off to Firestore. If any of them were to fail, no data is changed in the database.

Next, you store a user's notifications inside of their user document. For a small number of notifications this is fine, but do you need to download all of those notifications if you wanted to pull just an address or phone number like in the example in the above section? I recommend splitting them out into their own document (such as `/users/{someUserId}/metadata/notifications`), but ideally their own collection (such as `/users/{someUserId}/notifications/{someNotificationID}`). By placing them in their own collection, you can query them and use [`QuerySnapshot#docChanges`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docchanges) to synchronize changes and use Cloud Firestore triggers to send push notifications.

#### Refactored Function

```
1. Get the trade offer document</li>
2. Once the retrieved, do the following depending on the result:
  - If failed or empty, return an error
  - If successful, do the following:
    a) Pull out the sender and receiver's IDs, along with any items in the trade.
    b) For each item in the trade, check if any are unavailable and once the check has completed, do the following depending on the result:
      - If any item is unavailable, do the following:
        a) Decline the trade
        b) Return the list of unavailable items
      - If all items are available, do the following:
        a) Create a new write batch containing:
          - Create a document about the trade
          - Edit the trade offer document to accept it
          - Create a notification for the receiver
        b) Commit the write batch to Firestore
        c) Once the commit has completed, do the following depending on the result:
          - If failed, return an error
          - If successful, return the traded items and the trade's ID
```

Because the steps here depend on each other, this is a good candidate to use `async`/`await` syntax.

To see this in action, closely study this:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase-admin";

// insert here: https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527

async function firebaseAcceptTradeOffer(tradeOfferID, userData) {
  const tradeOfferDocRef = db.collection("tradeOffers").doc(tradeOfferID);

  const tradeDoc = await tradeOfferDocRef.get();

  const { senderID, receiverID, sendersItems, receiversItems } =
    tradeDoc.data();
  const itemsArray = sendersItems.concat(receiversItems);

  // TODO: Check if this is an accurate assumption
  if (sendersItems.length == 0 || receiversItems.length == 0) {
    success: false,
    message: "One-sided trades are not permitted",
    detail: {
      sendersItemsIDs: sendersItems.map(({ itemID }) => itemID),
      receiversItemsIDs: receiversItems.map(({ itemID }) => itemID),
    },
  };

  const listingsColQuery = db
    .collection("listings")
    .where("status", "==", "listed");

  const uniqueItemIds = Array.from(
    itemsArray.reduce(
      (set, { itemID }) => set.add(itemID),
      new Set()
    )
  );

  const foundIds = {};

  await fetchDocumentsWithId(
    listingsColQuery,
    uniqueItemIds,
    (listingDoc) => {
      // if here, listingDoc must exist because we used .where("status") above
      foundIds[listingDoc.id] = true;
    }
  );

  const unavailableItemIDs = uniqueItemIds
    .filter(id => !foundIds[id]);

  if (unavailableItems.length > 0) {
    // one or more items are unavailable!
    await tradeOfferDocRef.update({
      status: "declined",
    });
    return {
      success: false,
      message: "Some items were unavailable",
      detail: {
        unavailableItemIDs,
      },
    };
  }

  const tradeDocRef = db.collection("trades").doc();
  const tradeInstanceID = tradeDocRef.id;

  const batch = db.batch();

  batch.set(tradeDocRef, {
    tradeOfferID,
    senderTradeStatus: {
      created: true,
      sentToSeekio: "current",
      inspection: false,
      sentToPartner: false,
    },
    receiverTradeStatus: {
      created: true,
      sentToSeekio: "current",
      inspection: false,
      sentToPartner: false,
    },
    postagePhotos: [],
    inspectionPhotos: [],
    senderPaid: false,
    receiverPaid: false,
    senderUploadedProof: false,
    receiverUploadedProof: false,
    senderID,
    receiverID,
    messages: [
      {
        message: `Trade created. A representative, will message this chat shortly with instructions and postage address. If you would like more information about the trading process, head to seekio.io/help. Thank you for using Seekio!`,
        sender: "System",
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
      },
    ],
  });

  batch.set(
    tradeOfferDocRef,
    {
      status: "accepted",
      tradeInstanceID,
    },
    { merge: true }
  );

  const receiverNotificationRef = db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(senderID)
    .collection("notifications")
    .doc();

  batch.set(receiverNotificationRef, {
    from: auth.currentUser.uid,
    fromUsername: userData.username,
    type: "tradeOfferAccepted",
    time: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    seen: false,
  });

  await batch.commit();

  return {
    success: true,
    message: "Trade accepted",
    detail: {
      tradeID: tradeInstanceID,
      senderItems,
      receiversItems,
    },
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
try {
  const tradeResult = await firebaseAcceptTradeOffer(someTradeId);
} catch (err) {
  // if here, one of the following things happened:
  //  - syntax error
  //  - database read/write error
  //  - database rejected batch write
}
```

Comment: This is amazing. thanks a bunch man honestly. I'm going to begin reading through this now, looks like a fantastic lesson, will comment back how I end up, you're a legend

Comment: I've just got an error saying that uniqueItemIDs.filter() is not a function. When I return uniqueItemIDs in the console, I can see its an object and the ids are in the Entries array. Is there a way I can take those entries out? calling .entries() doesn't seem to work either. TIA mate!

Comment: @squish Ah, I was trying to be smart and forgot that `Set#values()` returns an `Iterator` not an array (`Set#entries()` does the same). The `Set` stuff was a new addition here as in the past I've normally used `const dedupeMap = {}`, `arr.forEach(e => dedupeMap[e.id] = true)`, and `const uniqueIds = Object.keys(dedupeMap)` for this. Fixed now.

Comment: Hi sam, your method is implemented and its honestly great. I've learnt a lot from this section of code. Such as batches and batch commits, how to use async await and return properly. Thanks a bunch you're a legend.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you are returning a promise where it can't be resolved you must await its result. Additionally, you must be returning a value from within a promise `then` chain, at minimal the last `.then()` needs to be returning a value, this can also be done within a `.finally()` method.

Using Get from any firebase resource, realtime, firestore, and storage are all Async processes and must be awaited. in your case, you are missing an await for the return:

```js
 var tradeOffer = db.collection("tradeOffers").doc(tradeOfferID);
  return tradeOffer
```

and you don't appear to be returning anything inside your .then() statements, I would suggest a complete rewrite of what you are trying to so you are returning values as they are needed.

Comment: THank you for your comment, I'm struggling to get the promise result from a search from firebase, I'll edit my answer now